# How to interrupt QThread from PyQt GUI?

Tags: user-interface, pyqt4, qthread

I'm writting an application that encrypt an image. The main problem is that i want to add to my GUI option to interrupt (or even terminate) an encrypting thread (while it is working) just by clicking an gui button. Gui and algorithm work fine (ia also provide a gui's progressbar connection) but when the thread start to procced i can't click anything on gui (even the terminating button). Beside that button is properly connected becuse if there occured an error in thread and gui i still working i can click the button and it terminate the process. 
I thought that gui froze because thread was defined in gui function so I've moved it out of gui to main program function. 
I want to point out that i don't create therad subclass (as Maya Posch suggest http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/)

Here is the code of main function:

```
def main():
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   cryptoThread = QtCore.QThread()
   prog = ProgramWindow()
   worker = ic.imageCryptographer()
   worker.moveToThread(cryptoThread)

   prog.progressButton.clicked.connect(lambda: prog.interruptEncrypting(cryptoThread))
   prog.startEncrypting.connect(cryptoThread.start)
   worker.encryptSignal.connect(prog.progressbar.setValue)
   worker.done.connect(lambda: prog.endEncrypting(cryptoThread, worker))
   cryptoThread.started.connect(lambda: worker.compute(prog.shareFlag, prog.binMatrix))

   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

functions from class ProgramWindow:

```
def interruptEncrypting(self, thread):
    thread.terminate()
    thread.wait()
    self.interrupt()
    return

def endEncrypting(self, thread, worker):
    self.keys = worker.keys
    thread.quit()
    self.progressbarWidget.setVisible(False)
    self.saveOption.setEnabled(True)
    self.cryptoWorkdeskOption.setEnabled(True)
    self.openCryptoWorkdesk()

def interrupt(self):
    self.progressbarWidget.setVisible(False)
    if self.state==1:
        self.buttonSwapWidget.setVisible(True)
    elif self.state==2:
        self.keyChooseWidget.setVisible(True)
```

Variables: shareFlag and binMatrix has no connection to thread communication (their are variables necceseray to compute worker methods. StartEncrypting is a signal emited from one of ProgramWindow function.

Thanks in advance for any advice where I made a mistake or what should I do.

Comment: I'm not one hundred percent sure about this but I guess it's because you do the encryption not (only) in the class `ic.imageCryptographer` but you moved it to a new object when doing `lambda: worker.compute(...)`. Although you moved `worker` to `cryptoThread` the calculation is wrapped into this new lambda object which is under control of the main thread. So you would have to connect to `worker.compute` directly (and set the arguments in some separate function `worker.initialize(...)`).

Answer (score 1):

Yep, just tried it and can confirm what I already indicated in my comment. Although you moved `worker` to `cryptoThread` (and therefore all its methods) the moment you connect `cryptoThread.started.connect(lambda: worker.compute(prog.shareFlag, prog.binMatrix))` you create a new lambda object which is not running within `cryptoThread` but within the main thread. That's why it does not run besides your main application. You would have to connect `cryptoThread.started.connect(worker.compute)` and pass the arguments in some additional initializer / configure method.

I tested it with the following code:

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self, parent)

        self.t1 = QtCore.QThread()
        self.moveToThread(self.t1)
        self.t1.start()

    def do_stuff(self):
        while True:
            print 'loop'
            time.sleep(1)

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.worker = Worker()

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('start', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.worker.do_stuff)  # connect directly with worker's method do_stuff
        #self.button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.worker.do_stuff())  # connect with lambda object containing do_stuff

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
main = MainWindow()
main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```